# Time threshold maps plotting in R

Tags: r, time-series, visualization

I am trying to plot *time threshold maps*, proposed by Fryzlewicz. The relevant paper is: [Time-Threshold Maps: using information from wavelet
reconstructions with all threshold values simultaneously](http://stats.lse.ac.uk/fryzlewicz/allth/allth.pdf).

[image]

**Questions:** Is the top plot in `Figure 1` a heat map? How can I plot this in `R`?

Comment: I tried to plot it as heat map, but it looks different. Could you please give me any hits to start? Thank you.

Comment: IMHO, this question fits the _Cross Validated_ SE site the best. I suggest to consider migrating it there or the _DSP_ SE site, as @maj noted.

Comment: Tough one -- I'd consider 'how to plot in R' on-topic for this SE, although then the question should contain more detail about what is being plotted and what's been tried so far.